# Div element height is automatically set to zero

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a fairly straight forward layout - main div, which floats left. Within it I nest other div's with style clear both. Here is a simplified version(all items have sub-divs):

```
<div id="wrapper" class="floatLeft">
    <div id="mainMenu" class="clearBoth">
        <div id="item1" class="clearBoth">
        </div>
        <div id="item2" class="clearBoth">
        </div>
        <div id="item3" class="clearBoth">
        </div>
     </div>
 </div>

 .clearBoth {
      clear: both;
  }
  .floatLeft {
      float: left;
  }
```

Problem is item3's height is computed to be 0 for whatever reason. All the elements within it spill out into the wrapper div. It looks horrible because main menu div has a background etc. If I add style of "overflow:hidden" to item 3 it looks fine - the question is why? I don't understand why is there an overflow? Most importantly though - why is the height of item3 computed to be 0?

Here is a link to jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uPtCd/

Comment: Can you reproduce it somewhere like http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: What about your CSS and a fiddle?

Comment: How are we supposed to determine the problem when all you've provided is a bunch of `<div>`s?

Comment: Sorry, let me add that.

Comment: `div` elements with no content will have a computed height of zero.   The float overflow issues are a separate problem.

Comment: But I do have elements in there, they show up below the main menu. What are the common reasons for overflow if I never explicitly set div's height?

Comment: In your question, the divs are empty. In your jsFiddle, they're not. Please read this: http://sscce.org

Comment: @NindzAI Based on your fiddle, it's due to your `div`s inside of `#item3` also being floated. There's no content within the content flow of `#item3` to use for computing `#item3`'s height because those inner `div`s are floated.

Comment: @ajp15243 This indeed fixed it. Thank you. Could you elaborate on why exactly it worked. I don't entirely follow your initial explanation. My basic assumption was that if div contains sub-elements they are going to be taken into account for size calculation.

Comment: @NindzAI I posted an answer as an explanation, with a link to another SO question containing solutions. Technically your question is a duplicate :).

Answer (score 1):

Just give the `<div class="clearBoth"></div>` after the the `<div>s` mentioned in your Item 3

```
<div style="float:left; width:45%; margin-top:5px"> <span class="label">Laser Power</span>

                <input type="checkbox" class="value lasersetting" id="laserEnable" />
                <label for="laserEnable">On</label>
            </div>
            <div style="float:right; width:55%; margin-top:5px">
                <div style="float:left; margin-left:10px; margin-top:10px" id="laserSlider"></div>
                <input type="text" style="float:center" class="value lasersetting" id="laserValue" value="0" valType="number" min="0" max="100"></input>
            </div>

<div class="clearBoth"></div>
```

This should fix!

Also just a suggestion, you don't need to give **"class="clearBoth"** to all parent DIVs. All you need to do to clear the **"float"** is give an empty DIV with class clearBoth where you FLOATING DIVs Ends. Like we are doing for the above DIVs!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a CSS expert, so I'll refer you to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3293340/1883647). The basic idea is that there's this concept of "flow" in HTML/CSS that determines how content/markup is organized and laid out by an HTML/CSS layout engine. The issue you're having here is that, based on your fiddle, your `#item3` contains only floated child elements. Floated elements are removed from "normal flow". When the layout engine in your browser is determining how `#item3` should be sized and laid out, it looks for "normal flow" content inside of the element. Finding none, it computes the height to 0. The width follows the rule of `block` elements since it's a `div` without a modified `display` CSS rule.

If you want to keep the child elements of `#item3` floated, you can explore some alternate solutions in [this (duplicate) SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/218760/1883647). Alternatively, remove the `float` rules on the child elements.

Note that this concept of "flow" has changed a bit in HTML5 to be a more general concept called [Content Models](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/content-models.html).