# menu div sending main div far away

Tags: jquery, css, html

Sorry for the weird title, I don't know what else to call it.  So here is my question.  I am making a new site from scratch, and I'm am not very fluent in HTML, but I made a main div, and a top menu div, and when I tested it, it was fine.  Then I added a side bar to it, and when I tested it, the menu was all the way on the left, so when I tried to fix it, the main div was sent out to the middle of the page along with the menu, away from the sidebar.  Here is my css code:

```
body
{
  font: "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
  background-image:url("http://www.wallchan.com/images/mediums/2000.jpg");
  color: #696969;
}

#main
{
  position: absolute;
  left:105px;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color:     #ADFF2F;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
}

h1
{
  font: Georgia, serif;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #cc9900;
  color: #996600;
}

#sidebar
{
  position:absolute;
  left:0; top:92px; bottom: 0;
  width: 90px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color:  #48D1CC;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

#menu
{
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}

#menu li
{
  display: inline;
}

#menu li a
{
  background-color:     #87CEFA;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 2.8em;
  color: #034af3;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}

#menu li a:hover
{
  background-color:     #7CFC00;
}
```

Here is my main HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>PHP Demo</title>
    <link href="site.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="sidebar">
      <p>Test</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu">
      <?php include("header.php"); ?>
      <div id="main">
        <h1>Welcome to the Pantheon Inc. website! </h1>
        <h2>We strive to make your life easier!</h2>
        <?php include("footer.php"); ?>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and here is my header code:

```
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="projects.php">Projects</a></li>
<li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

P.S. Also, I would like to know if there is any way to turn my menu into a drop down menu?
like when you hover over it, there might be a little jquery animation making it drop down its sub-components.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using `position: absolute` in this case.
Floats would be better - [flexbox](http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/holy-grail/) (if the browsers you are targeting support it) would be best.

#### HTML

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="projects.php">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="sidebar">
    <p>Test</p>
</div>

<div id="main">
    <h1>Welcome to the Pantheon Inc. website! </h1>
    <h2>We strive to make your life easier!</h2>
</div>

<footer>footer here</footer>
```

#### CSS

```
#menu
{
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

#menu li
{
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

#main
{
  float: left;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color:     #ADFF2F;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#sidebar
{
  float: left;
  width: 90px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color:  #48D1CC;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

footer { clear: both; }
```

Other issues:

1. there is no a `<div id="menu">` closing tag, you need to add it
2. you have 2 identical IDs, `menu`. You need to get rid of one.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cu64x/)** with floated layout

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I haven't read your entire post, but this seems like a position problem.
when you add position absolute on one element, it will lose the normal flow on the page, to recover this flow you can add on your main container.

```
overflow:hidden;
```

also you can add

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

you will get the same result

[What is the meaning of the terms "Normal Flow" and "Out of Flow", in terms of HTML, CSS and Browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293340/what-is-the-means-of-terms-normal-flow-and-out-of-flow-in-terms-of-html-cs)

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp